# What is the antonym of to toggle?

Tags: antonyms

What is the antonym of "to toggle"?

A search shows both **to untoggle** and **to detoggle** in use, but I could find neither in dictionaries.
(I could find untoggle as "to unfasten by removing a toggle from its loop" in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/untoggle), but that seems to be a different meaning for the word.)

Another alternative could be to oppose "to toggle on" with "**to toggle off**".

So, how should I write these sentences?

> - You cannot * *untoggle* this choice.
> - This option cannot be * *untoggled* while Foo is selected.
> - Selecting Fizz will * *untoggle* all Buzz options.

Comment: It is unclear what you think "to toggle" means. Do you think it means "to turn on"? What does a dictionary say "to toggle" means? Last I knew it meant to change between two options. These may be "on" and "off", or they may be "red" and "blue"; in which case there is no opposite.

Comment: Can you explain why you think there should or even could be an antonym to toggle, please?

Comment: @AndyT It seems you were right on the money, I had a wrong concept for "to toggle".

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin asking why a word "could" exist is strange. All words could exist, any word could exist. I don't understand what you mean, unless you mean generally the same as AndyT.

Comment: Thanks and no, it isn't possible that there could be an antonym to "toggle" any more than an that old forum favorite, an "opposite" to "black and white.

… unless you meant generally that just because a word exists, doesn't mean it has a meaning.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting an earlier answer:

> Toggle as a verb is based on the concept of operating a [toggle switch](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/toggle-switch)

This definition means the thing with a value, say a light switch or a radio-button, has one of two possible value: e.g. on/off; 1/0; yes/no; on/off; or more poetically yin/yang; order/chaos; etc.

Toggling is switching it from one value to the other. Switching it back isn’t called (*) *untoggling*. Toggling it *again* switches it back. *Repeated* toggling switches back and forth between the values.

I don’t think there is an antonym beyond simply *not toggling*.

If you have a boolean choice, and **toggling** is switching to the other one, how can there be an antonym?

You switch or you don’t.  You can’t choose a blank or no value. In a boolean world items are *on* or *off*; there is nothing else.

Comment: It might sound a bit *zen*, but the question as phrased implicitly requests a word for that ‘nothing else’.

Answer (score 3):

If a synonym of "to toggle" is to "to switch to state A if in state B, or to switch to state B if in state A", then the opposite of that is not to switch, or not to toggle.

However, based on the 3 sentences you wrote, to me it sounds like you're writing a program/designing a UI with binary switches, or checkboxes. Assuming this is the case, then selected/deselected (turn on/turn off, activate/deactivate) should work:

> - You cannot **deselect** this choice.
> - This option cannot be **deselected** while Foo is selected.
> - Selecting Fizz will **deselect** all Buzz options.

Answer (score -1):

Toggle as a verb is based on the concept of operating a [toggle switch](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/toggle-switch)

This is a switch that can have one of two positions, "off" and "on".  As a verb, you could pick a term appropriate to the context:

*"de-select" an option"*
or
 *"toggle-off" an alarm"*

Comment: No, a toggle switch is called that because of it's action -- it "flips" distinctively between positions.  It may be selecting between any two settings.

Comment: If you desire to use **toggle**, I agree with your statement:

 Another alternative could be to oppose "to toggle on" with "to toggle
 off".

It meets the KISS principal and avoids ungainly grammar.